# Password protected excel data to be imported in remote sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel, t-sql, import-from-excel

I have an Excel which is protected by password(I know the pwd), I have to import the data from one of the sheets of excel file(.xls) and update one of the tables in the DB located in remote server.

Following is the dummy code I used.

```
Declare @ZipTemp NVarchar(255)   

set @ZipTemp = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
            'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Addresses.xls;IMEX=1',
            'SELECT top 1 ZIP FROM [Sheet1$] where ZIP = "328301"'))`


Update [dbo].[Addresses_Temp]
set State = 'CA', Zip = @ZipTemp 
where Zip = '32830'`
```

but the problem with it is:

1. It can only be used in local machine server
2. It cannot access password protected files.

Please let me know if anyone knows about it.

Comment: IMHO Export the target sheet to a new file without password protection and place the file to the remote server's file system

Comment: @peterm I was thinking the same, but if there is method to access it as it is, then it will be wonderful, as the sheet includes classified data.

Comment: A) Have you *tried* adding a password to the connection string?  and B) have you *tried* opening it on a remote server with a UNC?  What is the error that you get?

Comment: I tried using Powershell commands but it will go in hacking category which is not recommended in my company, so I m doing what peterm told and @RBarryYoung, you cannot open .xls if it is password protected. I m getting cannot access file error.

Comment: Thanks for you time, I m done with it actually.